# R data.frame, group some inputs into "data$inputs"

Tags: r

I have a `dataframe`, loaded from file, such as

```
F[1] F[2] ... [F100000] <Output>
1 0 ... 1 6.25
1 1 ... 0 7.22
...(5000 rows)
```

I want to represent this data as `data.frame` where `data$inputs` is inputs from `F[1]` to `F[100000]` and `data$output` is outputs to use this `dataframe` this way:

`randomForest(outputs~inputs,data=data)`

But I have no way how to group `F` inputs into `data$inputs`

I wrote some functions but it seems awful:

```
loadDescriptors <-function(input){
  rd = read.csv(input, sep = " ", header =TRUE)
  rd <- rd[,colSums(is.na(rd))<nrow(rd)] #Delete empty columns
  na.omit(rd) #Delete Empty rows

}
getDescriptors <- function(data){
  return(grep("F",colnames(data), value=TRUE))
}
getFormula <- function(input){
  return(as.formula(paste("outputs ~ ", paste(getDescriptors(input), collapse="+"))))
}
```

**Added**:
Sample of data:

```
> d <- loadDescriptors("Test.stg")
> str(d)
'data.frame':   4316 obs. of  325 variables:
 $ F.0.    : int  2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ F.1.    : int  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ F.2.    : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ F.3.    : int  0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ F.4.    : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ F.5.    : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ F.6.    : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ F.7.    : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ F.8.    : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ F.9.    : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ F.10.   : int  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
...
 $ F.98.   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  [list output truncated]
```

And the output is:

```
> str(d$Activity)
 int [1:4316] 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 ...
```

I can refer to any field of `data.frame` for example:

```
> str(d$F.2.)
 int [1:4316] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

But I want to group all inputs to refer to inputs, as `data$input`, how can i do it?

Comment: Could you run str(dataframe) and post the result? I think that might make it easier to understand what data you have.

Comment: Your question is how to find all columns with names: `F.0.`, `F.1.` etc.? If so, then something like `DF[,colnames(DF) %in% paste("F.", 1:1000, ".", sep = "")]` might help. I'm not sure, though, what the question is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not currectly sure if I understand what you want but if I do, the following should help:

```
inputs <- dataframe[-length(dataframe)]
outputs <- dataframe[length(dataframe)]
```